# Theming a custom form

Tags: 6, forms, theming

I have themed Drupal7 forms, cannot do the same with 6 ...

I have:

```
function _my_form() {
    $output="";
    $form=drupal_get_form("my_form");
    $output=theme("my_form",
        array(
            "element"=>array(
                "my_form"=>$form
            )
        )
    );

    return $output;

}

function MYMODULE_theme()
{
    $themes = array(
        'MY_form' => array(
            'template'=>'my_form',
            'variables' => array('element' => NULL)
        )
    );
    return $themes;
}
```

If i do a var_dump($element["my_form"]) in my_form.tpl.php i only get a superlong string with the html form already rendered, while i expected to have an array with all the single form fields... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: is _my_form() a page callback or a page argument to be passed to drupal_get_form ? Usually you don't need to do drupal_get_form() - a theme call should be called automatically for you. Sorry I couldn't touch these for a long time.

Comment: @AyeshK `_my_form()` is a page callback, in that code.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should return a  render array in your theme function 
  `array('render element' => 'form')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   function _my_form() {
     return drupal_get_form("my_form");
    }

   function MYMODULE_theme()
    {
    $themes = array(
      'my_form' => array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'templates/my-form',
      )
    );
    return $themes;
   }
```